# TypeError: cannot read property 'getPackageInfo' of undefined in Frida

Tags: javascript, java, android, reverse-engineering, frida

Hi I am trying to call a method (getPackageInfo) using Frida, but i get this error:
`TypeError: cannot read property 'getPackageInfo' of undefined`.
This is the code:

```
Java.perform(()=>{
    const jPM=Java.use('android.app.ApplicationPackageManager');
    jPM.getPackageInfo.overload('java.lang.String','int').implementation=(pname,f)=>{
        console.log("Called => getPackageInfo (Flag="+f+", Pkg="+pname+")");
        return this.getPackageInfo.overload('java.lang.String','int').call(this,pname,f);
    }
});
```

And the error is from this line: `return this.getPackageInfo.overload('java.lang.String','int').call(this,pname,f);`

Answer (score 0):

The common way is to save the reference to the hooked method and reuse it when you want to call the original implementation:

```
Java.perform(()=>{
    const jPM=Java.use('android.app.ApplicationPackageManager');
    const getPImethod = jPM.getPackageInfo.overload('java.lang.String','int');
    getPImethod.implementation=(pname,f)=>{
        console.log("Called => getPackageInfo (Flag="+f+", Pkg="+pname+")");
        return getPImethod.call(this,pname,f);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have done this and now i get a new error: `TypeError: cannot read property '$getHandle' of undefined","stack":"TypeError: cannot read property '$getHandle' of undefined`. May this be happening because the method is called using the abstract method instead?

Comment: Also because i am getting these problems only in methods who are normally called using the abstract variant. For example here the method is called usually by using android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInfo.

Comment: Sorry if i spam comments, i can't edit them after some time. But may that error (the one i sent in the comments) be caused by the fact that I am calling the method passing it `this` which is undefined?

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried your Frida code snippet on a different app? May be the app uses some security measures that prevent Frida from functioning correctly? What phone, Android Version and Frida client and Frida server version do you use?

Comment: I have tried on different apps and different phones, it isn't the problem. I am using the last Frida Inject.